# How to include/ refer jackson-all.jar in maven

Tags: java, maven

I am unable to find the repository entry for jackson-all.jar
Not sure why rather i could see individual jackson jars informations.
So,
 how to refer the jackson-all.jar ?

Answer (score 6):

For Jackson 2 have a look at the [com.fasterxml.jackson](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.fasterxml.jackson) groups. I normally have the following added to my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

You may also need a jax-rs-module. See the [official download page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) or [github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for information on how Jackson is divided into packages.

Comment: Can you please fix the link for Download page? It's broken!

Answer (score 4):

`jackson-all.jar` does not exist as a Maven dependency.

The list of all artifacts in the group `org.codehaus.jackson` are at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson.

Just add `dependency` elements in your `pom.xml` for the artifacts you directly need in your application. Maven will make sure that all other artifacts these depend on will be included in your project.

**Edit:** If you use a Java IDE, it will help you look up the missing dependencies for every class you use in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled onto http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jr/jackson-jr-all - it looks like what you want. How you add that to maven though, i'm not sure.