# Java : How to map the json string returned by Oauth2 service to model class object

Tags: java, json, model, jackson, spring-security-oauth2

I have a oauth2 server which will return a json string containing access token,refresh token and their validity when a request with granttype,user credentials and client credentials comes.Below is the response string that i got.

```
{"value":"yu592e04-o9d5-8724-92a8-c5034df13cae","expiration":"Jul 25, 2016 4:14:31 PM","tokenType":"bearer","refreshToken":{"expiration":"Sep 24, 2016 3:14:31 PM","value":"bb6b7d65-a938-h75b-9cc5-d78b38e7adf9"},"scope":[],"additionalInformation":{}}
```

Now i need to map all these fields in the json string to a class.How can i do that.I need to map fields to the below class.

```
public class UserToken{
String accessToken;
Date accessTokenValidity; 
String accessTokenType;
String refreshToken;
Date refreshTokenValidity;
String scope;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using `Jackson` library.

Try this. The `refreshToken` tag becomes a class in java.

```
public class Convertor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String json = "{\"value\":\"yu592e04-o9d5-8724-92a8-c5034df13cae\",\"expiration\":\"Jul 25, 2016 4:14:31 PM\",\"tokenType\":\"bearer\",\"refreshToken\":{\"expiration\":\"Sep 24, 2016 3:14:31 PM\",\"value\":\"bb6b7d65-a938-h75b-9cc5-d78b38e7adf9\"}}";
        Convertor converter = new Convertor();
        UserToken token = converter.fromJson(json);
        System.out.println(token);

    }

    public UserToken fromJson(String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        UserToken token = (UserToken) new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, UserToken.class);

        return token;
    }

}

class UserToken {

    String value;
    String expiration;
    String tokenType;
    RefreshToken refreshToken;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getExpiration() {
        return expiration;
    }

    public void setExpiration(String expiration) {
        this.expiration = expiration;
    }

    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public RefreshToken getRefreshToken() {
        return refreshToken;
    }

    @JsonProperty("refreshToken")
    public void setRefreshToken(RefreshToken refreshToken) {
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "value " + value + "expiration " + expiration + "refreshToken.Expiration " + refreshToken.getExpiration()
                + " refreshToken.getValue: " + refreshToken.getValue();
    }
}

class RefreshToken {
    String expiration;
    String value;

    public String getExpiration() {
        return expiration;
    }

    public void setExpiration(String expiration) {
        this.expiration = expiration;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I updated the question with the class that i need to map these fields.I don't think ur exmaple will help me,because in the json string that i provided there are 2 field with label "value" and "expiration" and also the refreshtoken field contain 2 sub field that i need to seperate.

Comment: the first value field should map to accessToken and the second value field to refreshToken.Similarly the first expiration field should map to accessTokenValidity and the second to refreshTokenValidity.

Comment: Any solution from u??

Comment: Can u show the gradle plugin for the jackson library used here?

Comment: Check this dude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176104/how-to-include-refer-jackson-all-jar-in-maven